# Show that $\Gamma_f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\Gamma_f(x)=(x,f(x))$ is continuous, with $f$ continuous.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

The entire problem statement is,

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define $\Gamma_f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\Gamma_f(x)=(x,f(x))$. Show that $\Gamma_f$ is continuous.

My attempt at the proof (partially complete) is,

Consider $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Then considering $U$ as an open subset of the product topology, we have
$$U=\bigcup_{i}O_i\times O'_i$$ for $O_i,O'_i\subset\mathbb{R}$ open. Then we have,
$$\Gamma_f^{-1}(U)=\Gamma_f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i}O_i\times O'_i\right)=\bigcup_i\Gamma_f^{-1}(O_i\times O'_i)$$

Now from here I just want to jump and say $\Gamma_f^{-1}(O_i\times O'_i)$ is open since $\Gamma_f(x)=(x,f(x))$ and because $f$ is continuous, but I'm certain there's a couple more lines I need to write to fill in those details.

Is my approach even correct with this problem?

Thanks for any help or feedback!

Comment: You can prove $\Gamma_f^{-1}(O_i \times O'_i) = f|_{O_i}^{-1} (O'_i) = O_i \cap f^{-1}(O'_i)$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It's exactly what I was thinking to say in words, but mathematically. Thank you for your help John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f: X \rightarrow Y \times Z$ is continuous (if $Y \times Z$ has the product topology) iff $\pi_Y \circ f$ and $\pi_Z \circ f$ are both continuous (and $\pi_Y, \pi_Z$ denote the standard projections of a product onto its factors, we can also use $\pi_1,\pi_2$).

This follows from the fact that compositions of continuous functions are continuous, and $f^{-1}[U \times V] = (\pi_Y)^{-1}[U] \cap (\pi_Z)^{-1}[V]$ and sets of the form $U \times V$ with $U \subset Y, V \subset Z$ both open form a base for $Y \times Z$.

Apply this for all spaces equal to $\mathbb{R}$ and note that $\pi_1 \circ \Gamma_f = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\pi_2 \circ \Gamma_f = f$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous, if you take any sequence $x_n \to x $, you know $f(x_n) \to f(x) $. Now, you wanna show $\Gamma_f (x) $ is continuous. Take any sequence $(z_n)$ such that $z_n \to z $. If you show that $\Gamma_f (z_n) = (z_n, f(z_n) ) \to (z , f(z) ) = \Gamma_f (z)$, then you are done.

Comment: This is a great approach, but the book I'm using hasn't gone over sequences yet, so I can't quite use this yet. Thank you though for your answer.